# Set multiple Access SQL results as variables

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a SQL query that returns a list of 4 results (the AutoNumber ID and the names of 4 employees) like the below:

```
DB_ID |DB_AdjName|
------|----------|
97    |John      |
98    |Mark      |
99    |Tim       |
100   |Paul      |
```

I need to return the 4 results into an Access Form so they can be 'edited'. To do so, I need to store the 4 names as variables (such as var1, var2, var3 etc) so that they can be then input back into the text boxes on the form.

Is there anyway I can have the VBA loop this to set up the variables with each result?

The workaround I have at the moment, involves adding +1 to the AutoNumber and DLookup returning the name, which feels inefficient, as well as 'line-heavy', but also leaves it open to issues if the ID numbers aren't in a linear pattern.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Andre I'm not I'm afraid Andre, or I'd have not asked the question! Are you able to elaborate on it's use in this scenario?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You have data in a table, and want to edit it. This is usually done with bound forms. No code is necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to use the word edit there; just to clarify this isn't to edit a record in a table. I need to display the 4 names in 4 separate text boxes that are locked and enabled is set to False. To do this I need a variable assigned to each result in the row.